# Override get() in Django Class Based View to Filter

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm starting a new app and I'm trying my best to embrace Class Based Views. Ahhh, growing pains. I'm trying to do a simple filter here from a GET variable, if it doesn't exist I want to return all objects ordered by id desc, if it does, I want to filter, order and return the filtered list.

I'm writing 30+ lines of code to do this, so I *must* be doing something wrong, right? I tried overriding get_queryset() and now that I think of it, maybe I should be calling self.request.GET['search'] in get_queryset() to do this filtering. Is there a standard way of accomplishing this?

```
class MyModelList(AdminPageMixin, ListView):
    model = MyModel
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'template/list.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'search' in request.GET and len(request.GET['search']):
            search = request.GET['search']
            self.object_list = MyModel.objects.filter(advertiser__name=search).orderby('-id')
            context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list, search=search)
        else:
            self.object_list = MyModel.objects.all()
            context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list).orderby('-id')
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyModelList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = MyModelForm
        try:
            context['search'] = kwargs['search']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        context['form'] = form
        context['form_action'] = reverse('mymodel-add')
        context['form_display'] = 'hide'
        context['form_save_label'] = 'Add'
        return context
```

Secondarily, to complicate matters, I have a CreateView and an UpdateView that I would like to share the get() or get_queryset() and get_context_data() methods of my ListView. I'm sure that it's possible with a Mixin, but again, I'm looking for a standardized way of doing it. Suggestions? Here's the CreateView in which I'd like to share ListView's methods.

```
class MyModelAdd(AdminPageMixin, CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'templates/list.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('mymodel-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyModelAdd, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form_action'] = reverse('mymodel-add')
        context['form_display'] = 'show'
        context['object_list'] = MyModel.objects.all()
        return context

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        form = MyModelForm(self.request.POST)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        context['form'] = form
        context['form_action'] = reverse('mymodel-add')
        context['form_display'] = 'show'
        context['form_save_label'] = 'Add'
        return render(self.request, 'templates/list.html', context)
```

Comment: CBV do not necessarily mean less code

Comment: Thanks, @Samuele for that observation. I'll add that to my docstrings  ;)

Comment: class based views are a pain but it slowly gets better as you learn to refactor base classes better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are correct in your observation: you should definitely use `get_queryset` for filtering the list. I suggest something along the lines of:

```
class MyModelList(AdminPageMixin, ListView):
    model = MyModel
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'template/list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(advertiser__name__icontains=search)
        qs = qs.order_by("-id") # you don't need this if you set up your ordering on the model
        return qs
```

Second, if you really need to reuse code between List and other views, you'd be better off to write a separate function than use a mixin.

A side note: you don't need the `form_action` URL in your form; simply set `action=""` and it will POST to the same URL.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using form_action because I'm setting it differently in MyModelEdit and using the same form. context['form_action'] = reverse('mymodel-add') in the CreateView view and context['form_action'] = reverse('mymodel-edit') in the EditView, again calling the same html file. Thanks again.

Comment: "Second, if you really need to reuse code between List and other views, you'd be better off to write a separate function than use a mixin." - Do you know of any good examples of this?

Comment: Shouldn't that read: `if search: qs = qs.filter(advertiser__name__icontains=search)`?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to filter the data in 'get_context_data'.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyModelAdd, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form_action'] = reverse('mymodel-add')
    context['form_display'] = 'show'
    context['object_list'] = MyModel.objects.all(user=self.request.user)# that's will filter the user data
    return context
```